# I would like to add another parameter to json file using python script

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

returns

```
"messages": [  
    {  
        "text": "testing",   
        "ts": "1479967441.000004",   
        "user": "ray",   
        "type": "message",   
        "bot_id": "B379PT5AT"  
    },    
    {  
        "text": "SWAT start",   
        "type": "message",   
        "user": "john",   
        "ts": "1479967379.000003"  
    },   
    {  
        "text": "SWAT close",   
        "type": "message",   
        "user": "ray",    
        "ts": "1479967379.000003"  
    },
```

I would like  to add another parameter

```
"messages": [  
    {   
        "text": "testing",   
        "ts": "1479967441.000004",   
        "user": "ray",   
        "type": "message",   
        "bot_id": "B379PT5AT"  
        "icon": "URL...."  
    },   
    {  
        "text": "SWAT start",   
        "type": "message",   
        "user": "john",   
        "ts": "1479967379.000003"  
        "icon": "URL...."  
    },   
    {  
        "text": "SWAT close",   
        "type": "message",   
        "user": "ray",   
        "ts": "1479967379.000003"  
        "icon": "URL...."  
    },
```

Code:

```
import simplejson  
with open ('automation.json')as json_data:  
    data = simplejson.loads(json_data)  
    for r in  data['messages']:  
        key = messages['icon']  
        messages["icon"] = ("testing")  

outdata = simplejson.dumps(data)
```

Comment: will this icon field be same for each object? if no then where would you get this information?

Comment: i got  a json file 
i would like to run a python script  so that i can make the above change

Comment: @AjayGupta it will be the result of command that i will run

Comment: @omri_saadon i have made changes and such results are out

Comment: You should show your own code and attempts first - Stackvoerflow is not a coding service. Show your work, show what you've tried so far - then we'll gladly help.

Comment: @nlsdfnbch i have created a json file
which i would like to edit to create another parameter to the json file data

Comment: Yes, but that isn't code. Show us what python code you have written to solve this problem.

Comment: @nlsdfnbch i have posted the codes that  i tried

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Looping over `data['messages']` accesses a list of dictionaries, which is why your assignment didn't quite work. You have to access the dictionary first, and then assign.

```
 import json
 with open('automation.json') as data_file:
     data = json.load(data_file)['messages'] # you now have a the json as a python object.
 # If you want to always add the same value to each dictionary
 data = {d['icon'] = 'A Value you want' for d in data} # d represents a dictionary in data['messages']

 # other wise, lets say the icon is linked to the user:
 icon_urls = {'john': 'http://someurl.com', 'ray': 'http://someotherurl.com'}
 data = {d['icon'] = icon_urls[d['user']] for d in data}
```